springboot app launched on different port
I have a springboot application and I have defined several application properties files for different profiles. One of the profile 'localtest' has configurations defined in application-localtest.properties. Port is:

server.port=8081

I launch app:

mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=localtest

I understand that configuration is picked from corresponding profile file.
What I see is that tomcat is launched on port 8089 which is defined in application properties for another profile, while I expect it to be on port 8081.
Why this behaviour?

This question is similar to: How to use Spring Boot profiles?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
